# Import-PSSession $Session and Import-PSSession $Session -AllowClobber is not working

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

Anyone would help me this? I've tried this solution also [Import-PSSession : Proxy creation has been skipped for '%' command, because PowerShell couldn't verify its name as safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801433/import-pssession-proxy-creation-has-been-skipped-for-command-because-powe) but still it doesn't work for me.

It says that when i enter Import-PSSession $Session
WARNING:Proxy creation has been skipped for the following command: 'TabExpansion', because it would shadow an existing local command. Use the AllowClobber parameter if you want to shadow existing local commands.

Then i try the Import-PSSession $Session -AllowClobber. Still it doesn't work. The error says:
Import-Module : There were errors in loading the format data file:
Microsoft.PowerShell, , C:\User\User\AppData\Local\Temp\temp_3b3f42b5-ea81- .....

Comment: why not add a `-prefix xx` parameter to `import-session`? In this way all imported cmdlets become for example `Get-xxProcess`.

Comment: Im sorry but i'm new to PowerShell. Can you put the whole syntax how to do that? And what is the -prefix?

Comment: `Import-PSSession $Session -prefix "xx"`. And give a read to `get-help import-session -full`.

Comment: @C.B. Thank you. Sorry i know its so late.